# Variable is used before being assigned in typescript, when type provided

Tags: typescript

I have this code in typescript, but I am not understanding why it is telling me the variable is used before being assigned:

This only happens when I add the type to the `database` variable. This is a Vue/Quasar based project, using Typescript. Note, if I specify the type to be 'any' then I don't have any issues, though I would rather avoid going that route if I can.

Can anyone suggest what I could be doing wrong, and a possible solution?

```
  import { SQLiteDBConnection } from '@capacitor-community/sqlite';

  let database: SQLiteDBConnection;
  try {
    database = await sqlite.retrieveConnection(this.connectionName);
  } catch (error) {
    // ignore
  }

  try {
    if (!database) {
      // workaround an issue if `retrieveConnection` fails
      await sqlite.closeConnection(this.connectionName);
    }
  } catch (error) {
    // ignore
  }

  try {
    if (!database) {
      database = await sqlite.createConnection(this.connectionName);
    }
  } catch (error) {
    // ignore
  }

  if (!database) {
    throw new Error('unable to create or retrieve connection');
  }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you initialize your database variable as such:

```
  let database: SQLiteDBConnection | null = null;
```

Now your variable can be either `null` or a database connection, and it's always defined, which seems to be what you're assuming further in your file.

Comment: Or just `let database: SQLiteDBConnection | undefined;`, which has the same effect but doesn't require a change in runtime code